# Pros/cons of using ActiveRecord select() to create temporary attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, select

I've been looking for something like what's described under point 4 here  http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/five_activerecord_tips since I switched to Rails/AR from PHP with pure SQL (no ORM).

In short if you add a `.select()` on a query that does an aggregation, calculation or `IF()` and tacks on `AS alias` then AR ensures the records you get back all have an extra (temporary) `alias` attribute that's correctly populated. (Temporary as in results of other queries won't have the attribute)

As the blog post indicates this means you can do multiple counts with a single query. You can also denormalize data by pulling columns from dependent tables or making calculations between columns and putting the result in a temporary/disposable attribute on the resulting records.

This seems great, so my question is why I don't see this done more often and whether there are good style reasons to avoid it.

One of my coworkers was concerned it risks confusion because someone else searching for `def alias` would never find it. I can see it would be a bad idea to do this on records that were likely to be passed around extensively so that the call to `.alias()` would be quite removed from the query that creates it, but for a report or a simple show/index action it seems like it would be quite safe and useful.

It's  also just a case of "if we do this routinely it won't be confusing", i.e. people would quickly learn to search for `(def|AS) alias` when they don't know where something is coming from.

I guess more broadly I've never understood why you wouldn't do simple calculations like these in a query if you could - better to have them run in C code that's already iterating over the collection than in a second loop running in Ruby, which is frequently necessary if you don't do the above. Without getting into PL/SQL or stored procedures why not push as much work as possible into the highly optimized DB layer? Especially simple stuff that's not business logic.

I'm keen to know if there are good reasons this is not good style or examples of how it might go wrong, or alternatively if there are others out there that use this as a standard idiom and wouldn't be surprised by it.

Comment: This feature is super handy when you need it. I use it for doing multiple aggregations in a single query without resorting to hand-coded SQL.

Comment: One reason is you can't use Model.includes(:association) so no eager loading. It also makes the the AR object brittle (attr depending on a sql string etc, no clear SRP). Ideally it should be used in a separate QueryObject, where it can be 'contained' and easily tested